# How to get Date Object in Ionic 4

Tags: angular6, ionic4

I want to get Date Object in Ionic 4, but i am getting Date not found, i am not able to compile the code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-bookingdetail',
  templateUrl: './bookingdetail.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bookingdetail.page.scss'],
})
export class BookingdetailPage implements OnInit {
   d = new Date();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For setting a  component in IONIC 4 use toISOString function :

```
<ion-datetime  [value]="today"></ion-datetime>

ngOnInit() {
   const now = new Date();
   this.today = now.toISOString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the variable to the Date type.
Then for the easiest-of-uses: you can just console log the result when the page is loaded.

```
export class BookingdetailPage implements OnInit {
   d: Date = new Date();
}     

ngOnInit() {
   console.log(this.d);
}
```

OUTPUT (in console)

> Mon Jan 21 2019 08:35:52 GMT+0100 (Midden-Europese standaardtijd)

Comment: I tried this, but same result i am not able to compile it. I am using Ionic 4 and Angular 6

Comment: @Kuldeep Strange! Can you update your question with the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

```
export class BookingdetailPage implements OnInit {
  public currentDate: String;
  date: number;
}

constructor(){ 
 this.date = new Date().getTime();
 this.currentDate = (new Date()).toISOString();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**